# Since yesterday's Debian update, X11 does not appear to load my ~/.Xmodmap file, what would the most proper way of loading it be?

Tags: debian, xorg, xmodmap

Due to lack of multimedia keys on the current keyboard, I bind F12 to play/pause, but that stopped working since yesterday, after to a large batch upgrade from the last month or so.

So, what I am wondering is, what is the proper way to load it? Is there a line I could put in .Xdefaults, or will I have to create additional files?

Doing "xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap" in the terminal appears to load everything properly, but the new keybindings do not work.

Comment: The automatic loading of `~/.Xmodmap` is not performed by the X server, but either by the startup scripts invoked by your display manager (xdm, lightdm, kdm, gdm, …) via scripts in `/etc/…/Xsession` and friends, or by your window manager or desktop environment. How do you start X (`startx` or which display manager), what WM/DE do you use?

Comment: Used to use GDM, and I do not remember why, but I switched to KDM, way before yesterday though. I use Xfce.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this line to your `~/.xsessionrc`:

```
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

The suggestion was taken from [here](https://wiki.debian.org/Keyboard/MultimediaKeys#Autostart_for_every_WM) and they used `~/.xmodmaprc` instead of `~/.Xmodpam`, perhaps the name has been changed?

`man xmodmap` also seems to think that `~/.xmodmaprc` is the default but does not specify if it is read by default:

```
   The filename specifies a file containing xmodmap expressions to be exe‐
   cuted.   This  file is usually kept in the user's home directory with a
   name like .xmodmaprc.
```

Comment: That worked, but apparently no more, not sure why, and if I even updated my system since.